# How do I see CPU microcode version?

Tags: windows

How do I see CPU microcode version in Windows 7? Is there some application that will show it?

I'm just curious to see if under windows my CPU is using newest microcode version. If I remember correctly, microcode updates used to be issued together with windows update, but at one point they moved them to hotfixes that need to be downloaded manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SiSoft Sandra shows microcode version on the Hardware->Processors page.  It also gives advice on whatever might be the latest version, and if yours is outdated.

Please note that it takes a short while for the page to load (up to two minutes).

As of this writing, on my PC, the reported microcode is MU062D0710.  Sandra says it's the latest available.  YMMV

Comment: To make the microcode informationshow up fast, right-click on Processors module, use module settings to limit displayed information to include DMI/SMBIOS only.

Comment: HWiNFO also shows the microcode version.

Answer (score 17):

For first core, look at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0
```

For example:

"**Update Revision**" = 0xba - current latest microcode (from mcupdate_*.dll)

"**Previous Update Revision**" = 0xb3 - default original microcode version (from BIOS)

"**Identifier**" - Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 11

"**Platform Specific Field 1**" - 0x80

Microcode is taken from **c:\Windows\System32\mcupdate_GenuineIntel.dll** (or **mcupdate_AuthenticAMD.dll**) using "Identifier" and "Platform Specific Field 1". For Intel, you can search for "DataVersion" UTF-16 string from mcupdate_GenuineIntel.dll to see all included ucode versions. For cpu id from example: "6fb-80,ba" (format is FamilyModelStepping-PF,ucRevision in hex).

Comment: For reference, you can easily show this information from the commandline: `reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0`

Comment: `reg query HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0 | find "e R"` prints only the microcode version, both "live" (after possible patching from Windows) and at boot time (from BIOS).

Answer (score 2):

Check the version number of the microcode dll: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2493989

The dll is Mcupdate_genuineintel.dll and the latest version for you depends on your Windows version.

This page has the actual downloads of the microcode update: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936357

Comment: I don't even have that file on my system. If there no way to read that form the CPU itself line in say GNU/Linux?

Comment: I'd imagine not. The microcode is an OS function for communication with the CPU, not a direct CPU function. The CPU would not be able to tell you the microcode internally to itself.

Comment: That is **NOT** true. In Intel's programmer's manual, volume 3A, chapter 9, section 9.11.7 it is clearly described how to read the current version of the microcode, so I know that the procedure is possible. It is possible to detect the current version of the update or to see if no update was done. Unfortunately, the RDMSR command must be run from ring 0 or real mode, so I can't just write an application on windows that will give me the information.

Comment: Then I stand corrected. I assumed that because it resides in Windows as a dll, unless that dll is some sort of firmware update system, the microcode in that dll would only be applicable inside the Windows environment.

Comment: The Microcode is ephemeral, meaning every power down of the CPU it is reset and has to loaded again! So if you check in Linux, you get the Version included in your Linux Distribution (or the base version included in your BIOS/UEFI). This won't tell you what version Windows installs on boot!

Comment: @AndrejaKo In linux the currently loaded microcode can be seen by `cat /proc/cpuinfo` in the line labeled "microcode".