# How To Find CPU Microcode For BIOS Patch

Tags: cpu, bios

I have recently been wanting to upgrade my laptop's CPU but as it only has support for up to a dual core i3 I was looking to find the required Microcode for patching/updating my BIOS. I haven't been able to find this Microcode for an AMI BIOS and CPU 3940XM, for example. Could someone point me in the direction of where to find this data and how to find it in the future if ever needed.

System: 
Asus X54H-BD1BH 
CPU: B950

P.S. Yes, I have realized that the TDP has increased from 35 to 55 Watts but if I can find the Microcode I will be copying some of this guides data: [A guide to upgrade a laptop cooling capability](http://therandomlab.blogspot.com/2012/01/laptop-cooling-mod.html?m=1)

Thanks in advance

Comment: [How you determine the Microcode for a processor is well documented](http://superuser.com/questions/355691/how-do-i-see-cpu-microcode-version) Windows even shares this information with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks again for the help. After posting this question, I was eventually able to find another Asus laptop that used the 2860QM, the N53SV. After finding this I was able to successfully extract the CPU support patches and then add them to my own BIOS via MMTool.