# Windows 10 migration to new CPU

Tags: windows-10, cpu, migration

I am changing my CPU persisting actual motherboard, i.e. socket is the same and motherboard supports new CPU chip. I remember the old days when upon CPU change Windows had to be reinstalled.

Does still this apply to Windows 10 which I have?

Comment: "If I change my CPU to new one what shall I have to do about to make Windows 10 continue function?" - Windows 10 licensing is connected to the motherboard not the CPU, so you won't have to do anything, to make it functional unless you replace the motherboard.  If it's an OEM machine that means purchasing a new license, retail license, can be migrated to the new machine seamlessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends.

IF is it a new CPU with same socket, then mostly you don't need to do anything, and windows will just update its drivers for the new CPU.

IF is it a new CPU with different socket, meaning you'll have a new motherboard as well. Then, you'll have to install motherboard drivers along with the new chipset driver. Also, you will need to make sure (before changing the motherboard) to register your Windows 10 product key to Digital Key to reactivate the windows 10 on the new motherboard. (This is optional if you have a retailer version of Windows 10, and mandatory if you have an OEM version of Windows 10)

To register your Product key to a Digital Key go to `Settings > Update & security  > Activation` and then sign in using a Microsoft email account (Hotmail, Live, Outlook, Microsoft ..etc). Then register your product key to your Microsoft Account, when you're done, you're ready to swap the motherboard and run the windows and use the same Microsoft account that you linked the digital key to it, and your windows will be activated.

Read more about it:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activation

Comment: When does a CPU require a "driver"??? Let alone integrated graphics and PCI controllers.

Comment: @iBug CPU drivers are already included within the chipset driver along with PCI controllers. A CPU alone won't require a driver because it will be already installed and updated with its settings automatically from OS side.

Comment: A CPU alone never requires a driver. Only PCH does. CPU is a processing unit that reads and executes instructions from RAM. Thus an OS is often said to be "built for" a CPU architecture. Because the binaries in an OS is in the format of a specific CPU arch, the CPU can directly execute it without any prerequisites. If a binary contains instructions that's not meant for a CPU, it won't execute at all.

Comment: @iBug **A CPU alone never requires a driver.** is only half true. Microcode updates  are only for the CPU and uploaded/updated after every PowerOn [see this Q&As](https://superuser.com/questions/355691/how-do-i-see-cpu-microcode-version) by BIOS/Uefi/Windows.dll